# MySQL installation on Fedora leads to Failed to start mysqld.service error

Tags: mysql, environment-variables, fedora

I installed MySQL on Fedora Linux 39 but when I try to check the status of the server I get the following -

```
> mysqld.service - MySQL Server
> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
> Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
>              └─10-timeout-abort.conf
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-12-15 13:55:40 IST; 7min ago
> Docs: man:mysqld(8)
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
> Process: 463372 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> Process: 463384 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> Main PID: 463384 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
> Status: "Server shutdown complete"
> Error: 98 (Address already in use)
> CPU: 386ms
> 
> Dec 15 13:55:38 trishas-laptop systemd[1]: Starting mysqld.service - MySQL Server...
> Dec 15 13:55:40 trishas-laptop systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
> Dec 15 13:55:40 trishas-laptop systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> Dec 15 13:55:40 trishas-laptop systemd[1]: Failed to start mysqld.service - MySQL Server.
```

Please help with setting the environment variable MYSQLD_OPTS.

I have also installed mysql server, so that isn't the issue.